# How to implement ringing (incoming call) notification in Ionic 5

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a voice call project in my ionic 5 / Angular app.
I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging as my notification service for Android and IOS.

I want to implement ringtone or ringing notifications for the application, like Microsoft Teams or other messaging app on incoming calls.

Is there any native plugin or tools to support this feature? Or should I create a native functions inside my cordova platform?

I am currently tinkering with fcm notifications using vibrating pattern, sound, and some properties. Is it right to use default normal notification as an incoming call notification?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have a look at this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications

Comment: You can also use `Phonegap-Push-Plugin` Check these Examples: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#sound

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I think both plugin can send a notification only when the app is present or running in the background, can it send a notification directly when my app is not running ? Thank you for answering!

Comment: Yes, it will send notification even if your application in not running or not in background.

Comment: @EvanGunawan. Hello, were you able to show some alert is app is not running  rather than just get notification in notification center